# Google forms, sheets, apps script and maintaining (player infection status) arrays

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I want to ask people at a science fair wander around and use a Google Form (via browser on their phone) to record the IDs of other players they encounter. Then I want to use this information to show how an infection spreads amongst the players at the fair over time.

I think my first task is to work out how to use the information submitted via the Form to update an infection array for each player i.e. Player A met Player B, so look at the arrays for A and B, and update each array according to some rules e.g. if Player B has an infection A, update the array of Player A to include this infection A.

Update: I want to use an array because there will be many different infections, and I will also introduce antibiotics and vaccines (to subdue/remove infections).

Hopefully it is clear what I want to do, I'd appreciate advice on a sensible way to get started.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for working out the logic of a process flow.  You can use an "On Form Submit" trigger to cause code to run when the Google Form is submitted.  That will give you "real time" reaction to what is happening.  You'll need to structure your data so that it can be linked.  But, something like that is "off topic" to Stack Overflow.  It's definitely an interesting project, and something that people might be willing to help you with, but not a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks, understood. I only just started with GAS and Sheets - there seem to be so many ways I could approach this I can't work out how to get started. I can't find any tutorials that cover what I need to do, and this text from the main documentation seems a big limitation if I understand it correctly: "A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead."

Comment: If you are looking for general advice or tips, you might get some answers on [Link to Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)  How much help you get can depend upon how well your question is worded, and what your expectations are.  Your project has some fairly complicated data connections, which might be a good fit for some interesting things that can be done with JavaScript objects.  But you'd need someone who has a good understanding of that to figure it out.  This could be a time consuming project and be a lot more work than you think.

Comment: A quick search led me to some open code about an epidemic simulation.  [Epidemic Simulation on Git Hub](https://github.com/fastred/epidemic-simulation/tree/master/js)  That was committed 4 years ago, and there is no explanation of how to use it.  You can view that persons info and there is a way to contact them.  Apps Script can certainly do what you want, but as with anything, you could waste a lot of time going down roads to nowhere unless you have a well communicated logic for how this will work.

Comment: thanks 'Sandy'. i joined the GAS community. the simulation project is a bit advanced for me, and not quite what I am trying to do I think - i just want people at an event to use a google form to manually log who / what they meet, and in the background process these interactions to chart the spread of different pathogens i.e. a met b, b has v1 so now a does too. I am making some progress - learning about how to get data from sheet, process the arrays, and how to trigger scripts. hopefully i'll be able to post some working code here